# How to delineate, filter some cells, then concatenate in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take data that is concatenated in excel and delineate it, then remove any names that are not on another document, then remove the number from the beginning and concatenate it back together. He is an example:

```
261: SPwq EB, 261: SPf EB,524: Tier Standard 01, 261: Ser EB,524: Tier Standard 01,733: sdfP Stream,747: Lifestyle TV, 733: Stream
```

and I need it to look like this after filtered: `Select Compartment, Lifestyle, Stream`

There is another document I am using to reference whether the number associated with the name is to be included. This is the one step I do not have any VBA code for, the rest of the process is already automated. Right now I have a break in my VBA code and I am doing this manually with formulas and vlookups, but not to the degree I could copy and paste a macro.

Any code you could provide would be a huge help! Thank you!

Comment: Can anyone help solve this?

Comment: It looks like VBA `Split` function (and maybe `Join`) may be what you're looking for.